# Eclipse String cache is wrong, == does not work as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, string-pool

I have a simple application with a main method that compares two literal strings:

```
public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String first = "a";
        String second = "a";
        System.out.println(first == second);
    }
}
```

When I run this program in **Eclipse**, I get `false` as result. But when I compile and run this program by the **command line**, I get `true`.

The result should be `true` for both. Why does Eclipse return `false`?

I have tested it using JDK 7 and 8.

---

Note that I am aware that comparison with `==` compares for identity.

The JLS requires `"a"` to come out of the internal String cache, for both variables.

```
String first = "a";  // Creates instance, stores in cache and returns
String second = "a"; // Should return instance from cache
```

However, if I run this from Eclipse I get `false` for the comparison, so both instances seem to be different although the JLS requires them to be the same.

Therefore, see [JLS§3.10.5 String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal **always** refers to the **same instance** of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) - are "**interned**" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Comment: Do not compare object types with `==`. Simple as that.

Comment: That code is required by the language specification to print `true`, so I don't think that's the code you're running when it prints `false`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why I got different results for the same application depending on how I compile and run.

Comment: Not sure why people are down-voting. The question seems clear to me. Not nice to scare off new people without so much as a reason why.

Comment: I know that == compares references. But that's not my question. I actually don't know why people are down voting if they also don't know the answer.

Comment: order by  
up vote
0
down vote
Maybe you should reformulate the question emphasazing you wanna know about the difference between compilers, not about object comparison

Comment: It cannot print false. Because jdk will refer to same location where it stores the literal `"a"`.

Comment: @Phil I can't reproduce that. In fact, IntelliJ gives me a warning that `a == b` is always `true`.

Comment: @Jaumzera how could OP have made their question any clearer? The title and text of the question clearly states they're getting different results and the question is literally _"Why?"_

Comment: @Phil Report it as a bug, then. ["Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class `String`."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Comment: @Radiodef never mind, I was playing with the values and didn't notice I'd made them different. Chalk it up to end-of-week madness

Comment: I hope the edit made it clearer, voting for reopen. @LucasYoshioka You can avoid a situation like this by highlighting differences, stating your intend more explicit, elaborating the question. Still, the question does not contain enough information to reproduce the issue as some already mentioned they can't reproduce this with their Eclipse. Please add your exact eclipse version and possibly also plugins.

Comment: When you get a different behavior for different compilers, you should include exact version numbers for the compilers. It may be a bug which is unlikely to be present in all versions of the compiler.